# Am I over weight for this bike I bought

Tags: weight, heavy, clydesdale

My weight is 240 pounds (109 kilograms).

I bought a miele velo gr1 they said it will hold my weight but wheels only have 32 spokes.  Are they right?

Comment: Are you sure it's a Velo GR1 or is it a Veneto GR1?

Comment: Also, it's not just about the spokes. 32 spokes on each wheel, when laced and tensioned right, can support a lot of weight. It's the frame you'll be worrying about, but I think that for as long as you only use this for casual commuting, it'll be fine.

Comment: 240 what?  In lbs the bike should take it no problem, in kg definitely not.

Comment: OP is in the US, assuming pounds.

Comment: I'm no expert on bikes. But we weigh about the same. The only time I thought that I was too heavy for a bike, was when I was on a fully carbon fiber trek. I have three GT bikes. Two are road bikes with carbon fiber front forks. and they hold my "clydesdale" weight just fine thank you very much.... ;-) Unless you eat like a "clydesdale" you should be fine.

Comment: @Gandolf989 avoid eating hay and oats when riding a bike with a carbon fibre fork?

Comment: @gschenk I don't eat much hay or oats. I do appreciate a really good oatmeal stout though.

Comment: 32-spoke wheels should easily carry your weight.  It's more a question of the tires, rim, etc.  But generally 32 spokes indicate a reasonably robust wheel overall, since fewer spokes will be used on lighter weight wheels, as this is considered more "sexy".

Comment: I don't have an answer but I wonder if any manufacturers provide weight ratings for entire bikes/individual components? Even if the components of your wheels are not rated, maybe you could use other products as a "benchmark" to estimate the capacity of your components. Isn't there some safety standard that says what weight a bike has to support?

Answer (score 2):

The bike should be fine for your weight, assuming you use the bike for its intended purpose.  Which would be on-road riding, not off-road riding or other high impact activities.

For your information, 32 spokes is not that little,  wheels with less spokes are also often rated for up to 109KG.

Comment: Agreed, *if* the wheels are properly built and use quality components. If OP wants to make sure they should have a professional check the spoke tension and truing of the wheels.

Answer (score 1):

After searching the Miele site for a rider weight rating and finding no rider weight limit specification I turned to Trek for a roughly equivalent bike thinking that a similar bike would have a similar rider weight limit. (per pateksan's suggestion)

The [Trek Verve 2 disk bike](https://www.trekbikes.com/us/en_US/bikes/hybrid-bikes/recreation-bikes/verve/verve-2-disc/p/28003/?colorCode=bluedark) is in the same price range with an aluminum frame and 32 spoke alloy wheels. Trek rates their bike at:

> **Weight limit**  This bike has a maximum total weight limit (combined weight of bicycle, rider, and cargo) of 300 pounds (136 kg).

Even Trek's least expensive hybrid bike, the FX 1, is rated at 300 pounds.

I've ridden a bike with three full grown men on it - point A to B on a smooth surface - with no problems. You will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

[image: This bike has less spokes than that]

Apparently this is a Tour de France bicycle, so the rider would probably weigh less than 70 kg (or some 150 pounds). However, it has 16 or 18 spokes on the front (I think).
So, a well made wheel should be strong enough for its intended use.
However, check the warranty terms related to wheels "out of true" or broken spokes - and considering you are at the top weight range, use the maximum recommended pressure in tires and check often.